# ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS on wordpress page

Tags: ssl, https

Hi Im developing a page in wordpress but not working on https, when I try to access show me this error:
[image]

I try to use the plugin WP Migrate but it still not working, how can I resolve this?

Comment: Based on the question, I assume you don't have an SSL set up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if you have any 301/2 in your htaccess file.

OR if you are using a plugin, check for duplicates

Answer (score 0):

I know this should ask for more details in a comment but I don't have a reputation of 50.

Could you please include your .htaccess file.  It is likely that you have redirects in there and you might be getting into a loop.

Also, do you have any plugins installed that might be trying to redirect?